# Plotting |z-2| < 1 under w = z/(z-1)

Tags: plotting, complex, visualization

How can I plot the image of `|z-2| < 1` under the transformation `w = z/(z-1)`? The expected result should look something like this.

[image]

Comment: What is the relationship between $x$, $y$, and $z$ in your equations and diagram on the left?

Comment: Take a look at [ComplexRegionPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexRegionPlot.html). Look at the "Mapping Complex Regions" in the "Applications" section.

Comment: @MarcoB `z = x + i y` and `w = u + i v`.

Comment: It looks like the numerator of w should be 2, not z. Compare to the 2 in the inequality. So the right picture is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- We mapping the region `ImplicitRegion[Abs[z - 2] < 1, {x, y}]` to another region by the `z`( identity mapping) and `2/(z - 1)`.

```
plot=Block[{z = x + I*y}, 
   ParametricPlot[#, {x, y} ∈ 
     ImplicitRegion[Abs[z - 2] < 1, {x, y}], PlotRange -> 4, 
    Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
    AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.05]]] & /@ {ReIm[z], ReIm[2/(z - 1)]};
GraphicsRow[plot]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. A good code is a commented code.

Answer (score 4):

First plot:

```
ComplexRegionPlot[Abs[z - 2] <= 1, {z, 0 - 2 I, 4 + 2 I}]
```

[image]

After transformation:

```
transformed = Abs[z - 2] <= 1 /. First@Solve[w == z/(z - 1), z]
ComplexRegionPlot[transformed, {w, 0 - 2 I, 4 + 2 I}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With z= x+ y I and w:

```
w[x_, y_] = (x + y I)/(x + y I - 1);
```

we can vary x from 1 to 3. And y from -Sqrt[1 - (x - 2)^2] to Sqrt[1 - (x - 2)^2], we can plot the image of the circle:

```
ParametricPlot[
 ReIm[w[x, y]], {x, 1, 3}, {y, -Sqrt[1 - (x - 2)^2], 
  Sqrt[1 - (x - 2)^2]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-1.5, 1.5}}]
```

[image]